# disable user interaction while loading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, loading

is it possible to disable user interaction while loading? in my application, when the user inters his login info and presses a button to login I want a loading indicator to show and to disable all user interaction while its loading including disabling the back button/gesture, is there a way to achieve that? any help is appreciated

Comment: Create a transparent , full screen view overlap the page , place the loading indicator at the center of the view .

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you further explain on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting the stack layout of my page under an Absolute layout along side a loading overlay that looks like this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                 HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

               //contents of the page....

    </StackLayout>
    <BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
             BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
             InputTransparent="false" 
             IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" />
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Source={x:Reference Page}}" 
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" 
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and changing IsBusy in code will activate the loading overlay

Comment: I applied this solution but still the user can interact with the page while the activity indicator is running.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/redth-org/BTProgressHUD .

It disables user interaction while it shows on screen , you can dismiss it when the loading is finished .

[image]